# Jquery Asynchronous call return undefined value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, jquery-callback

I have gone through many topics on stack overflow for jquery asynchronous AJAX requests. Here is my code.

```
funciton ajaxCall(path, method, params, obj, alerter) {
var resp = '';
$.ajax({
    url: path,
    type: method,
    data: params,
    async: false,
    beforeSend: function() {
        $('.black_overlay').show();
    },
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        resp = callbackFunction(data, obj);
        if(alerter==0){
            if(obj==null) {
                resp=data;
            } else {
                obj.innerHTML=data;
            }
        } else {
            alert(data);
        }
    },
    error : function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    },
    complete: function() {
        removeOverlay();
    },
    dataType: "html"
});

return resp;
}
```

The problem is, when I use asyn is false, then I get the proper value of resp. But **beforeSend** doesn't work.

In case, I put async is true, then its **beforeSend** works properly, but the resp value will not return properly, Its always blank.

Is there any way to solve both problems? I would get beforeSend function and resp value both.

Thanks

Comment: BTW, callbackFunction seems undefined.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: What is the value of data?

Comment: See duplicate: you're attempting to return "resp" *before* the ajax call has even started.  It's "async".

Answer (score 1):

Use `async:false` and run the function you assigned to `beforeSend` manually before the `$.ajax` call:

```
var resp = '';
$('.black_overlay').show();
$.ajax({
    ...
```

Either that or learn how to use callback functions with asynchronous tasks. There are many nice tutorials on the web.

Answer (score 0):

1. Take the `resp` variable out from the function
2. Create one extra function `respHasChanged()`
3. when you get the data successfully, use the code
   `resp = data;respHasChanged();`

Answer (score 0):

You can restructure on this way, (why no use it in async way?)

```
function ajaxCall(path, method, params) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: path,
        type: method,
        data: params,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('.black_overlay').show();
        },
        dataType: "html"
    });
}
```

Call in your javascript file

```
ajaxCall(YOUR_PATH, YOUR_METHOD, YOUR_PARAMS)
    .done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);

        // DO WHAT YOU WANT TO DO

        if (alerter == 0 && obj !== null) {
            obj.innerHTML = data;
        } else {
            alert(data);
        }
    }).fail(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }).always(function() {
        removeOverlay();
    });
```